# return false not exiting the foreach loop

Tags: jquery

I want to return false or break the foreach loop. But it is not working.
This is the code which i have tried.

```
 function validate()
    {
        var validate="false";
        var atLeastOneIsChecked =  $("input[name='city[]']").is(":checked");
        if(atLeastOneIsChecked==true){

            $("input:checkbox[name='city[]']:checked").each(function(j){
                var city=$(this);

                $('select[name="category[]"]').each(function(i){

                    if(i==j){
                         if($(this).val()=="0"){
                         alert("Please select hotel category");
                         city.click();
                           //validate="false";
                            return false;
                       }
                        else
                        {
                            validate="true";
                        }

                    }
    // return false;
                }); 
                alert(j);
               // return false;
            });
            //return false;
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Please select atleast one city.');
            validate="false";
        }
        if(validate=="true"){
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

After the "Please select hotel category" the function should return false. But the form is posted after the alert. I don't what's wrong.

Comment: Where is your `foreach` loop!?

Comment: That's great: `var validate="false"`! Note, there is a [boolean type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) in JavaScript.

Comment: The click handler should return false. You're not supposed to return false after the handler has been evaluated.

Comment: @Cthulhu Its the jQuery's `$.each()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong, the mistake you are making is that you think this:

```
if($(this).val()=="0"){
    alert("Please select hotel category");
    city.click();        
    //validate="false";
    return false;
}
```

will prevent the click handler from posting the form. The return false part needs to happen in an event handler that is called before the one that submits the form.

Comment: can you please tell how should i do that?

Comment: It is in a loop so for the first if it is false, then the validate variable is set to false,but second time if the condition is true then the validate is set to true and the earlier false is overwritten so to avoid it i wrote return false. Can you please show me how to do it the proper way.

Comment: After the foreach loop i did this if(validate=="false"){
                    return false;
                }Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put the handler in your form tag like so:

```
<form onsubmit="return validate();" method="POST" action="post.php">

  ..

</form>
```

Then it will get invoked on submit, and if you return false in your function, it will prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: I have already done that. My question is the return false in the if loop does not return false or prevent the page from posting.

Comment: Is the hotelcategory failing validation?

Comment: Your problem is that you are returning from a loop. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZBhsy/4/ for a working scenario

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I modified my code

```
function validate()
    {
        var validate="false";
        var atLeastOneIsChecked =  $("input[name='city[]']").is(":checked");
        if(atLeastOneIsChecked==true){

            $("input:checkbox[name='city[]']:checked").each(function(j){
                var city=$(this);
                $('select[name="category[]"]').each(function(i){
                    if(i==j){
                        if($(this).val()=="0"){
                            alert("Please select hotel category");
                            city.click();
                            city.attr('checked', true);
                            validate="false";
                            return false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            validate="true";
                        }
                    }
                }); 
                if(validate=="false"){
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Please select atleast one city.');
            validate="false";
        }
        if(validate=="true"){
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Now it is working.